# Why do I need an space at the end for this SQL Injection to work?

Tags: sql-injection

This is the vulnerable code:

```
$order = isset($_GET["order{$i}"]) ? $_GET["order{$i}"] : '';
if (stripos($order, 'benchmark') !== false) die;
${"result$i"} = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {$tables[$i]} " . ($order != '' ? "ORDER BY `".$db->escape_string($order)."`" : ""));
```

`escape_string` doesn't filter backticks, so a possible payload could be

```
 winner`--
```

So the final url would be like `` https://vuln-app/?order0=winner`-- ``
It doesn't work unless I add a space at the end like this:
`` https://vuln-app/?order0=winner`--%20 ``
I saw this happen on multiple occasions, yet I still don't understand the reason.
I would truly appreciate if someone could shed light on the underlying reason behind why this space is needed and what it does.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What dialect of SQL is this? That may have an effect.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html), MySQL requires at least one whitespace character after the double dash for it to be registered as a comment.